# Replace all doubled or tripled letters with single ones

Tags: java, algorithm

Task:

> For a given string of characters consisting only of letters: a, b and
> c swap all doubled or tripled letters for single ones

I prepared such a code:

```
public static String doubleLetters(String str) {
        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder(str.length());
        if (str.length() == 0) return "";

        for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i-1) 
                    || str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i-1) && str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i-2))
            {
                ret.append(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return ret.toString();
    }
```

However, I cannot define the condition to take into account tripled letters.

> By entering "aaabbbccc" I want "abc".

> By entering "aabbcc" I want "abc".

> By entering "aaaaabbbbbbbccc" I want "aabbbc".

**IMPORTANT**
Letters that are converted to 1 letter are not taken into account.

Please help me how to approach this problem.

Comment: Have you tried a regex like `/([a-z])\1+/gi`?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I have heard about regural expressions but I do not want to use them consciously. I want to focus on loops and simple things because as you can see I have problems with them...

Comment: Due to your previous comment, @FlappyCat, I assume you are trying to solve some kind of programming test, so I will only give you a hint. Add a third OR to your IF statement, that tests for triplets, only if `i <=2`

Comment: What should happen for input `"aaaaa"`?

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov I should get two letters 'a', the first 3 letters 'a' will be converted to 1 letter 'a' and then, the remaining two will be converted to 1 letter 'a'.

Comment: But then shouldn't the resulting two letters `"aa"` be converted to a single letter `"a"`?

Comment: You want to copy the letter at `i` first, then skip over the next letter or two if they're duplicates.  That means that `i` would advance by a variable amount on each loop iteration, so a `while` loop would probably be preferable over a `for`.

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov No, we go from left to right and do not go back.

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear whether you want to replace only triple or double letters or a repeated character of any length by a single one. I'm assuming the latter one:

```
public static String eliminateMultipleLetters(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // better for loops than concatenation
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i + 1))
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    }
    sb.append(s.charAt(s.length() - 1)); // append last character
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Edit: to replace 3 characters by 1 as long as there are 3 and then 2 if possible, you could do as follows (the logic is very similar, just the step at the end gets more complicated):

```
public static String replace3or2Letters(String s) {
    if (s.length() < 2)
        return s;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length() - 2; i++) {
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i + 1)) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i + 2))
                i += 2;
            else
                i++;
        }
    }
    if (i == s.length() - 2) {
        sb.append(s.charAt(s.length() - 2));
        if (s.charAt(s.length() - 2) != s.charAt(s.length() - 2))
            sb.append(s.charAt(s.length() - 1));
    } else if (i == s.length() - 1) {
        sb.append(s.charAt(s.length() - 1));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

More elegant:

```
public static String replaceUpToXbySingle(String s, int x) { // x = 3 for you
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char last = 'c'; // whatever
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (count == 0 || s.charAt(i) != last) {
            if (count > 0)
                sb.append(last);
            last = s.charAt(i);
            count = 1;
        } else if (++count == x) {
            sb.append(last);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    if (count > 0)
        sb.append(last);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I did not explain exactly what effect I want to achieve. By entering, for example, 'aaabbbbccc' gets 'abc' from your code, but I should get 'abbc'.

Comment: @FlappyCat OK modified the answer and added also a solution for this. Not very elegant, sufficient for only 2 to 3 letters, otherwise we would need to generalize, e.g. if it is 2 to 6 letters.

Comment: @FlappyCat also added more elegant parameterized solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated response

If you want to replace groups of three, followed by groups of two, you need to build a list of contiguous frequencies. After you have this list, you could build a string by applying div/mod logic to the total.

I included a `Pair` class that extends `Map.Entry` which stores key-value associations.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class StringUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(dedupe("aabbcc").equals("abc"));
        System.out.println(dedupe("aaabbbccc").equals("abc"));
        System.out.println(dedupe("aaaaabbbbbbbccc").equals("aabbbc"));
    }

    public static String dedupe(String str) {
        if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
            return str;
        }

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        List<Pair<Character, Integer>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        char curr, prev = chars[0];
        int total = 0, i, add3, add2;

        for (i = 1; i < chars.length; i++) {
            curr = chars[i];
            total++;
            if (curr != prev) {
                pairs.add(new Pair<>(prev, total));
                total = 0;
                prev = curr;
            }
        }
        total++;
        pairs.add(new Pair<>(prev, total));

        for (Pair<Character, Integer> pair : pairs) {
            total = pair.getValue();
            add3 = total / 3;
            for (i = 0; i < add3; i++) {
                buffer.append(pair.getKey());
            }
            total %= 3;
            add2 = total / 2;
            for (i = 0; i < add2; i++) {
                buffer.append(pair.getKey());
            }
            total %= 2;
            for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                buffer.append(pair.getKey());
            }
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    private static final class Pair<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {
        private final K key;
        private V value;

        public Pair(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        @Override
        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public V setValue(V value) {
            V old = this.value;
            this.value = value;
            return old;
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Original response

All you would need to do it store a previous (`prev`) value and then just loop over the characters and append to buffer if current (`curr`) does not match the previous.

```java
public class StringUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(dedupe("aaabbbccc")); // "abc"
    }

    public static String dedupe(String str) {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        char prev = 0;

        for (char curr : str.toCharArray()) {
            if (curr != prev) {
                buffer.append(curr);
                prev = curr;
            }
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not explain exactly what effect I want to achieve. By entering, for example, 'aaabbbbccc' gets 'abc' from your code, but I should get 'abbc'.

Comment: @FlappyCat I went ahead and fixed my response based on your follow-up examples.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: count the number of consecutive occurrences of a character, and then print them in bulk, by dividing their number by three.

```
public static String doubleLetters(String str) {
        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder(str.length());
        if (str.length() == 0) return "";

        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i-1)) {
                count++;
                continue;
            }
            for (; count > 0; count -= 3)
                ret.append(str.charAt(i-1));
            count = 1;
        }
        for (; count > 0; count -= 3)
            ret.append(str.charAt(str.length() - 1));
        return ret.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, I cannot define the condition to take into account tripled
> letters.
>
> ```
> By entering "aaabbbccc" I want "abc".
>
> By entering "aabbcc" I want "abc".
>
> By entering "aaaaabbbbbbbccc" I want "aabbbc".
> ```
>
> IMPORTANT Letters that are converted to 1 letter are not taken into
> account.

Imagine this problem in three stages:

- First, generate a sequence (or a stream) of all the single, double, or triple letter occurrences in your input
- Next, replace  each of the occurrences in the sequence with its first letter
- Finally, put the sequence (or stream) back together into a single String instance

To realize this solution very readably, I would use a main method and a static helper method as follows:

```
public static String deDupe(String input) {
    String result = generateStreamOfOccurrences(input)
        .map(occurrence -> occurrence.substring(0, 1)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
    return result;
}

private static Stream<String> generateStreamOfOccurrences(String str) {
    String input = str;
    List<String> listOfOccs = new ArrayList<>();

    if (input != null) {
        while (input.length() > 0) {
            String occ = input.substring(0, 1);

            if (input.length() > 2 && input.substring(1, 3).equals(occ + occ)) {
                occ = input.substring(0, 3);
            }
            else if (input.length() > 1 && input.substring(1, 2).equals(occ)) {
                occ = input.substring(0, 2);
            }

            input = input.substring(occ.length());
            listOfOccs.add(occ);
        }
    }
    return listOfOccs.stream();        
}
```

The main function is easy to read.  It obtains a stream of letter occurrences in the String, each of which is a single, double, or triple of its first letter.  The work of obtaining this `Stream<String>` pipeline is encapsulated in the helper function `generateListOfOccurrences()`.  Then each of the elements in the stream are replaced by elements that consist of just the 1st letter.  Then they are joined together to form the result.

Comment: Are you sure you can compare (sub)strings like that?

Comment: @ciamej There is no problem with the comparisons, because the `input` template is not mutated until all the comparisons are made (and it's a local variable which is thread safe).

Comment: But won't `occ + occ` produce a different string object than `input.substr(1,3)`?

Comment: @ciamej It can and should.  It is asking the question "are the 2nd and 3rd letters in the input (if they are present) the same as the 1st?"  If it is, then the "occurrence" is made to be the 1st through 3rd letters of the input.

Comment: But in Java you need to use 'equals' to compare strings if you want to check if their contents are the same. By the way, there is no such method as `substr`...

Comment: @ciamej Correct.  The syntax has been edited.  Thanks for catching.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I cannot define the condition to take into account tripled
> letters.
>
> ```
> By entering "aaabbbccc" I want "abc".
>
> By entering "aabbcc" I want "abc".
>
> By entering "aaaaabbbbbbbccc" I want "aabbbc".
> ```
>
> IMPORTANT Letters that are converted to 1 letter are not taken into
> account.

Imagine this problem in three stages:

- First, generate a sequence (or a stream) of all the single, double, or triple letter occurrences in your input
- Next, replace  each of the occurrences in the sequence with its first letter
- Finally, put the sequence (or stream) back together into a single String instance

To realize this solution very readably, I would use a main method and a static helper method as follows:

```
public static String deDupe(String input) {
    String result = generateStreamOfOccurrences(input)
        .map(occurrence -> occurrence.substr(0, 1)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
    return result;
}

private static Stream<String> generateStreamOfOccurrences(String input) {
    List<String> listOfOccs = new ArrayList<>();

    if (input != null) {
        while (input.length() > 0) {
            String occ = input.substring(0, 1);

            if (input.length() > 2 && input.substring(1, 3).equals(occ + occ))
                occ = input.substring(0, 3);
            if (input.length() > 1 && input.substring(1, 2).equals(occ))
                occ = input.substring(0, 2);

            input = input.substring(occ.length());
            listOfOccs.add(occ);
        }
    }
    return listOfOccs.stream();        
}
```

The main function is easy to read.  It obtains a stream of letter occurrences in the String, each of which is a single, double, or triple of its first letter.  The work of obtaining this `Stream<String>` pipeline is encapsulated in the helper function `generateListOfOccurrences()`.